# AMI Asterisk Manager Interface Originate Action

Tags: c#, .net, asterisk

I am currently constructing a C#.NET wrapper for the Asterisk Interface Manager.

I can do simple things like transfers and hangups.  I am now in the process of building conference calling.  I can set up an n-user conference, but I have to do so in terms of "Action: redirect" on existing active channels.

What I'd like to do is route as now non-existent calls (i.e. there is no channel in "core show channels") to my context/extension that puts people in conference rooms.

But I cannot get "Action: originate" to work for anything.  What does originate take a channel as an argument when there is not channel yet?  What is it that you pass to the channel header?  SIP/ does not work for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misread your post.  You are writing a new wrapper to the AMI.  My first recommendation is, DON'T DO THAT.  My second recommendation is that unless you *truly* understand the issues with using a singular telnet server for all message passing (all clients receive all messages, and pre-connect sometimes cannot discern between the clients), and understand how it was implemented, is again, DON'T DO THAT.  Use a fairly well-tested and well-understood library and don't try to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Thanks.  The application is fairly simple and there is no events processing going on, so the traffic into and out of the AMI client application really isn't that bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What *exactly* are you trying to do?  You can't use a non-existent channel to bridge into a conference room.  If you're looking to create a conference, then have people called on their extensions (or on any number, really) and placed into the conference room, that's simple.

I assume you're using Asterisk.NET.  The originate command expects a number to dial (this is the channel), a context, and an extension to connect the call to within the dialplan (this can be hard-coded or can presumably be created through the AMI).

Say you set up a conference room on extension 300.  Your originate command would look something like this:

```
OriginateAction oc = new OriginateAction();
oc.Context = "YourDialPlanContext";
oc.Priority = 1;

// Channel is however you're dialing (extensions, SIP, DAHDI, etc.)
oc.Channel = "SIP/12125551212@Your-Sip-Prover-Peer-Name"; 
// or in the alternative
// oc.Channel = "ZAP/ZapChannelName/12125551212";

oc.CallerId = "9998887777";

// This is the extension you want dialed once the call is connected
// 300 in our example
oc.Exten = "300";
oc.Timeout = 60000;               // Our timeout in ms
oc.Variable = "VAR1=ABC|VAR2=25"; // If you need to pass variables to the dialplan

// Async should be set to true, unless you want your code to wait until the call
// is complete
oc.Async = true;         

// Go ahead and place the call
ManagerResponse originateResponse = AsteriskManager.SendAction(oc, oc.Timeout);
```

Voila!  You have now originated a call to your intended conference participant, and upon answering they will be directed into your conference room.

Comment: Yeah, the (limited) AMI docs use the term "channel" even with originate actions, hence I was probably misusing it.  Thanks.  I've heard mixed things about Asterisk.NET.  It kind of scares me that's there've been no public commits for ever two  years.

Comment: Honestly, it's because it's mostly complete, and the AMI has changed very little over the years.  It's very simple and straightforward, and handles a lot of the little BS you encounter when dealing with a telnet session.